# Como fazer um Json_Decode de um arquivo em formato json

Tags: php, json, arquivo, fopen

Olá,

Atualmente estou armazenando dados no formato json em um arquivo utilizando fopen.

`$json = fopen("$root/apil/Controllers/json/" . $this->getX_id() . ".json", "w+");
        $customers_results = $customers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        foreach ($customers_results as $customer)
        {
            array_push($file_content , $customer->x_id);
        }
        fwrite($json, json_encode($file_content));
        fclose($json);`

Até ai tudo certo o arquivo está sendo armazenado no formato JSON corretamente:
[image: elementos já inseridos no arquivos]

E como o esperado utilizo esse mesmo arquivo em outra classe, no entanto , ao realizar um json_decode da variável $file que "vem" do fopen me é retornado o seguinte erro:

`Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in ...`

O código que utilizo para coletar os dados do arquivo e posteriormente realizar um json_decode é esse:

`$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $x_id = $this->x_id();
        $y_id = $this->y_id();
        $file = fopen("$root/apil/Controllers/json/" . $y_id . ".json", "w+");
        $aux = json_decode($file);
        fclose($file); ...`

Vale ressaltar , que após pesquisar por soluções em Fóruns também tentei utilizar o `json_decode` da seguinte forma `$aux = json_decode(json_encode($file));` nesse caso não me é retornado nenhum erro ,porém, ao utilizar o `json_last_error()` me é retornado o erro 4 que segundo a documentação significa `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` , vale avisar que a variável `$y_id` também possui o conteúdo correto que no caso é o nome do meu arquivo.

Agradeço desde já se alguém puder me ajudar com esse problema.

Comment: No erro diz que o tipo da variável $file é resource e não string, confirme isso fazendo um echo gettype($file) pra descobrir o tipo da variável $file, se for resource mesmo e não string, tente de algum modo converter pra string

Comment: Obrigado pelo dica Douglas, realmente o arquivo era do tipo resource e para trabalhar com esse tipo de dado é um pouco trabalhoso.
Como no caso estou utilizando o arquivo somente para consulta acabei utilizando a seguinte instrução `$linha = file_get_contents("$root/apil/Controllers/json/" . $x_id . ".json");`

Comment: Muito bom! Sucesso brother!